# Ubuntu 18.04 missing dnsmasq service after install

Tags: dnsmasq, azure

I just deployed fresh Ubuntu 18.04 on Azure. Installed dnsmasq and noticed that it is missing service files completely. Daemon itself runs fine but I would like it to start on boot. How could I achieve this?

Comment: sudo apt install dnsmasq worked for me in ubuntu server 18.04. After the installation you can run the following command : sudo systemctl enable dnsmasq .

Comment: It does not work for me some reason. It does not provide the files necessary for service.

Comment: The desired service file should be in the dnsmasq package as I said in the answer. So if in your case it's not there , maybe it's not installed correctly or in a very unlikely scenario , it maybe a fault within the ubuntu repo.

Comment: Another solution for you is to clone to the [dnsmasq git repo](git://thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq.git) and compile and install it. It surely contains the missing "dnsmasq.service" file .

Comment: What are the chances I could somehow install it incorrectly? I just run "apt install dnsmasq-base"

Comment: So that's the problem . you can see in the output of " dpkg-query -L dnsmasq-base " that the .service file is not there . You should install dnsmasq pacakge not dnsmasq-base . And another option for you is to use systemd-resolvd which I think is more common in linux than dnsmasq.

Comment: I know how I managed to incorrectly install this. I opened my firewall only to azure.archive.ubuntu.com which is not enough. Opening the firewall to *.ubuntu fixed this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `dnsmasq` via

```
sudo apt install dnsmasq
```

at it contains the required service file :

```
$ dpkg-query -L dnsmasq | grep service -i    
/lib/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service
```

So the only thing you need to do is to enable the service to be executed during bootup.

```
 sudo systemctl enable dnsmasq
```

And it worked for me in ubuntu server 18.04.

Have fun using ubuntu ;)

Comment: that is the thing. I do not have that dnsmasq.service file at all. If I run "systemctl enable dnsmasq" I get error message stating that this service does not exist.

Comment: @kamsiinov The problem was that you had to install dnsmasq not dnsmasq-base.